# How can you get Kong API gateway OSS version to redirect traffic from a public address in an EC2 to backend services?

Tags: api, nginx, kong

I just installed kong on a test ubuntu EC2 server with instructions from [this site.](https://docs.konghq.com/install/ubuntu/?_ga=2.85618650.290537644.1636558953-1517572999.1636558953) It works and I am able to add services with routes. When I run curl commands inside the VM for the different services like `curl localhost:8000/reg` it works. However, when I try to access the endpoints from the public IP address it does not connect.

To check any connection issues I stopped kong and installed nginx and used proxy pass to point to one of the services and that worked when I visit the public IP address of the EC2. However if I stop nginx and try to start kong again I still can not access the apis from the public IP address, only the curl commands within the EC2 work. What am I doing wrong? Or what step did I miss to expose my services to the public IP address?
Below is my `kong.conf`

```
database = off
declarative_config = /home/aws/kong/kong.yml
```

and `kong.yml`

```
_format_version: "2.1"

services:
- name: web-service
  url: http://localhost:3333
  tags:
  - web-service-app
  routes:
  - name: web-service-route
    paths:
    - /
- name: account-service
  url: http://localhost:2222
  tags:
  - accounts-service-app
  routes:
  - name: accounts-service-route
    paths:
    - /account

- name: reg-service
  url: http://localhost:1111
  tags:
  - reg-service-app
  routes:
  - name: reg-service-route
    paths:
    - /reg
```

Comment: What listenning port have you used with nginx ? Perhaps the 8000 port is not open on your AWS security rule

Comment: You are exactly right, I don't know how I missed this... Thanks so much for the reminder @Ôrel